# 'android.disableResourceValidation=true' is experimental and unsupported in react native

Tags: android, react-native, npm, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am doing react native application. While creating android apk file getting following error

```
WARNING: The option setting 'android.disableResourceValidation=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'.
```

I have found my gradle.properties following

> android.disableResourceValidation=true

Even, I tried to set false, But, Still same issue getting.

I have knowledge in iOS, But, Android no idea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have added those lines to prevent build failure in Android while using svg files in react native app.                                                                     
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/239

Comment: To remove the warning delete the android.disableResourceValidation=true line in gradle.properties file

Answer (score 3):

go to **gradle.properties** and change it to `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=false`.
It worked in my case.

Comment: The option 'android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing' is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

for me works and I am sharing with you:

When Proguard is enabled (which it is by default for Android release builds), it causes runtine error To avoid this, add an exception to android/app/proguard-rules.pro:

`-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}`

[image]

Try build your app again.